# Add style to span if condition is true

Tags: php, html, css

I have this line `<h1>` tag, and its default color is `#ddd`:

`<h1><?php echo show_my_username($connection); ?></h1>`

I want to change its color if a PHP condition is true, so I'm doing this:

```
<h1>
  <span style="<?php if($user_color === 'green'){'color: green;'} ?>">
    <?php echo show_my_username($connection); ?>
  </span>
</h1>
```

I'm using a variable that can be equal to some colors like green or red, but when executing this, nothing changes in the text.
What I want to is to change the color based on the value of the variable. If `$user_color` is equal to green, add a style to the span to change the color to green. How can I do that?

Comment: <h1>
  <span style="<?php if($user_color === 'green'){ ?> color: green;<?php } ?>">
    <?php echo show_my_username($connection); ?>
  </span>
</h1>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The way you  made it, it won't print you anything because you don't print anything. To do so, you can either `echo 'color: green;'` or close and open your php to let see the html. As followed:

```
<?php if($user_color === 'green'){ ?> color: green;<?php } ?>
```

More information for the echo: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php